Angular Hydration throws exception when in production
I have an Angular 17 app that has SSR, Prerender and Hydration enabled.
angular.json
{
....

"prerender": true,
"ssr": {
  "entry": "projects/dental/server.ts",

...
}

app.module.ts
@NgModule({

...

providers: [
    provideClientHydration(),
...
,]

...

})

It runs fine when served locally but in production it throws errors.
Errors
app.component.html
@if ((service.option$ | async); as common) {
  <div class="page-body">
    <app-header [option]="option"></app-header><br/>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-spinner></app-spinner>
  </div>
  <app-footer [option]="option"></app-footer>
}

core.mjs
core.mjs:6373 ERROR TypeError: n is not iterable
    at m6 (core.mjs:13888:32)
    at U6 (core.mjs:16045:42)
    at V6 (core.mjs:15997:10)
    at T (core.mjs:18023:3)
    at template (app.component.html:1:1)
    at ZT (core.mjs:10988:5)
    at FC (core.mjs:12150:7)
    at z5 (core.mjs:12096:3)
    at j5 (core.mjs:12196:5)

When I inspect the core file I see this.
function locateDehydratedViewsInContainer(currentRNode, serializedViews) {
  const dehydratedViews = [];
  for (const serializedView of serializedViews) {
    // Repeats a view multiple times as needed, based on the serialized information
    // (for example, for *ngFor-produced views).
    for (let i = 0; i < (serializedView[MULTIPLIER] ?? 1); i++) {
      const view = {
        data: serializedView,
        firstChild: null
      };
      if (serializedView[NUM_ROOT_NODES] > 0) {
        // Keep reference to the first node in this view,
        // so it can be accessed while invoking template instructions.
        view.firstChild = currentRNode;
        // Move over to the next node after this view, which can
        // either be a first node of the next view or an anchor comment
        // node after the last view in a container.
        currentRNode = siblingAfter(serializedView[NUM_ROOT_NODES], currentRNode);
      }
      dehydratedViews.push(view);
    }
  }
  return [currentRNode, dehydratedViews];
}

I have attempted to isolate the components to identify the culprit but to no avail.
I have also skipped hydration for the components but I'm still getting same errors.
I also observed that when the error occurs the app losses its SPA capability and reloads on any page routing (change).
